# IN CASSANDRA, not able to create table with precision and scale values

Tags: cassandra

1. I am not able to create table using decimal precision
2. I am not able to create table using varchar length property

   `create table tf (a decimal(9,8) primary key );`

   `create table tf (a varchar(9) primary key );`

error :

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError:
  line 1:26 no viable alternative at input '(' (create table tf (a [decimal](...)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra, you do not specify the precision of decimals or lengths of varchars. See https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDataTypes.html.

You will also need to specify a primary key.